# jquery executes declared function without me clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wonder why the browser displays "logged in" without me having clicked on the link i id-tagged with clickhere. it displays it everytime i refreshes the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    function login(){
       alert("logged in");
    }

    $("#clickhere").click(login());

 });
</script>
```

i just want it to be displayed when i click on the link.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove () after login in JQuerys click() function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    function login(){
       alert("logged in");
    }

    $("#clickhere").click(login);

 });
</script>
```

Comment: exactly. But you don't want to call it (right now), you just want to tell jquery to use this function object later, when the click happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the method to jQuery's `click()`. `login()` mean execute-the-login-method. You have to pass method correctly as [ammoQ said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858816/jquery-executes-declared-function-without-me-clicking/1858836#1858836).

Or you can change your code like this. It will only call `login()` when click the `#clickhere`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    function login(){
       alert("logged in");
    }

    $("#clickhere").click(function() {
        login();
    });

 });
</script>
```